# Why does onclick event not fire in Firefox and Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, events, browser

I've got 8 layers of canvas in a div. There are four groups of two (off screen buffers and swapping). There's one layer for a background image, one layer for basically static drawing, one layer for animation. There's another layer for fading in and out another kind of animation.

While I was developing it, the onclick event worked fine, but has recently stopped working some of the time. Sometimes I have to click two or three times before it fires.

The only other environment I've tested it in (besides Firefox & Safari on Yosemite) is Safari on iOS (iPhone), and oddly, it works perfectly fine on iPhone.

I have a sample of html and a little JS below. I know people want a specimen that demonstrates the problem. I can't create one without giving you all of my original code.

This works, I just want to give you an idea of the situation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1"/>
            <script language="javascript">
                    function onLoad()
                    {
                            console.log("Loaded.");
                            context = document.getElementById("animatedCanvas_2").getContext("2d");
                            context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
                            context.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
                    }

                    function onTouch(e)
                    {
                            console.log("You touched me.");
                    }
            </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad();">
            <div id ="canvasDiv" ontouchstart="onTouch(event);" onclick="onTouch(event);">
                    <canvas id="backgroundCanvas_1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1;display:none;" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="backgroundCanvas_2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="textCanvas_1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:2;display:none;" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="textCanvas_2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:2" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="animatedCanvas_1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:3;display:none;" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="animatedCanvas_2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:3" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="successCanvas_1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:4;display:none;" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
                    <canvas id="successCanvas_2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:4;display:none;" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This specimen works. I'm wondering if any of you can conceive of a reason why onclick would only work sporadically if more code was added AFTER the console.log in onTouch.

NOTE: I don't set any events on DOM elements from JS.

Comment: id ="canvasDiv", fix it to id="canvasDiv"

Comment: Just to clarify:  the above code DOES WORK. I'm wonder why onclick would start being  so sporadic after adding code AFTER the console.log in onTouch.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible issue I can see is

```
<div id ="canvasDiv"
```

the space between `id` and `=`.

Other than that nothing looks glaringly wrong, but it's hard to say without being able to execute your code.

Comment: I removed the space, even though it's perfectly valid. No change in behaviour was observed.

Comment: @GregValcourt I think we'll need more code to provide assistance as there's nothing glaringly wrong with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find anything wrong with the functions or your call of them. However, it has been a hard lesson for me to stop mingling the languages of the Internet. Here's a rewrite of your script and HTML to have the JavaScript execute without having to be called in the HTML. It follows the current trend that Internet programming seems to have been taking the last very years.

It is working in Firefox, Chrome, IE11, and Safari (browsers I have from work). As far as I can tell, your code should work, and it is for me in all these same browsers. I don't know why you are having trouble. The best I can offer is to try this variation and see if it works.

```js
function onLoad() {
    console.log("Loaded.");
    context = document.getElementById("animatedCanvas_2").getContext("2d");
    context.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
}

function onTouch() {
    console.log("You touched me.");
}

window.onload = function() {
    onLoad();
    document.getElementById("canvasDiv").addEventListener("click", onTouch);
    document.getElementById("canvasDiv").addEventListener("touchstart", onTouch);
};
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="canvasDiv">
        <canvas id="backgroundCanvas_1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1;display:none;" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
        <canvas id="backgroundCanvas_2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:1" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
        <canvas id="textCanvas_1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:2;display:none;" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
        <canvas id="textCanvas_2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:2" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
        <canvas id="animatedCanvas_1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:3;display:none;" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
        <canvas id="animatedCanvas_2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:3" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
        <canvas id="successCanvas_1" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:4;display:none;" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
        <canvas id="successCanvas_2" style="position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;z-index:4;display:none;" width="100px" height="100px"></canvas>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Note**: Though the space between the `id` attribute and its value is incorrect, most modern browsers can compensate for that. Having said that, it should also be fixed (as it is in my example).

Comment: Are you implying that inline `onLoad` does not work in Safari? Because it does.. That would not be the issue. I just ran this fiddle in 3 different versions of safari and it worked. http://jsbin.com/xotehomoxi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: @Prefix No, I'm not saying that. What I said was that there is nothing wrong with the functions and that something is wrong with the call. However, that does not appear to be anything wrong with it, either. When I use `window.onload` instead of `body onload`, the script works perfectly.

Comment: yeah without more code/info from the OP I don't think we'll be able to help him. Needless to say the code he has provided is not the root of the issue.

Comment: @Prefix I rephrased my answer to better explain the intent behind it. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: onLoad is working, because there's a bunch of initialization that happens from onLoad, and it works fine. In fact, besides from a few other bugs, everything more or less works, except that the onclick event is not firing all of the time, and I'm sure of this because the first statement in the onTouch function is a console.log.

Comment: Also, I see no issue with spaces (I've removed the space just for humor). AFAIK <div id = "myID">some text</div> is perfectly valid.

Comment: @GregValcourt The only thing that should be happening because of your `onload` attribute is that execution of the `onLoad` function. Anything else is something else. All your `onLoad` function is doing is making a `console.log` entry and styling `canvas#animatedCanvas_2`. If you're not seeing "Loaded." in your console, then the `onLoad` function did not fire. Regarding the spaces, if you read my note after the snippet, I explained that there shouldn't be an issue caused by it.

Comment: @GregValcourt My apologies, I misread the issue. Either way, I can't reproduce the issue, so my original answer and statements stand for what they are. An alternative method of executing your script that follows the current development trends. Your version is working consistently for me. My version is working consistently for me. I'm sorry, but it's the best I can offer. Prefix has also noted that your code is working. Perhaps you have some security setting or plugin enabled on your Safari that is messing it up. I don't know, but we can't reproduce it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94861/discussion-between-greg-valcourt-and-christopher-esbrandt).

Answer (score -1):

Javascript uses camel casing (or something of that nature) try replacing `onclick` with **onClick** and `onload` with **onLoad**. That's all your script needs

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the casing used. The attributes `onclick`, `onload`, and `ontouchstart` are HTML, not JavaScript. The casing of `onTouch()` and `onLoad()` is also correct, matching the casing of the function names in the JavaScript.